# Why can't I update this attribute using the Set-ADUser PowerShell cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to update the `city` attribute for users in a specific `ou` using this script, but it does not work. The script completes without error. When I check the users, the `city` is still blank.

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=...' -Properties SamAccountName
foreach ($user in $users){
    Set-ADUser -identity $user.SamAccountName -City 'Alice'
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Hi N.Ma, welcome to stackoverflow! Try to give a more detailed description of your problem, what exctly you are trying to achive and we will try to help you!

Comment: I try to update the city Attribute for all users in a specific OU.  When I ran the above script, it does not set the city to Alice.

Comment: OK, so what *does* it say?  _What's the error?_

Comment: It does not return any error, the script is completed, but when check, the City field for these users still blank.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your `Get-ADUser` returns nothing, so the `foreach` loop is never entered.

`Get-ADUser` with the `-Filter` parameter doesn't *fail* if no matches are found, it quietly returns an *empty collection*.

A `foreach` loop over an empty collection or `$null` is simply never entered, so overall you get a *quiet no-op*.

<sup>Note that you never need `-Properties SamAccountName` in a `Get-ADUser` call, because `-Properties` is only needed to return *additional* properties for every result object, whereas `SamAccountName` is part of the *default* set of properties.</sup>

Therefore:

- you need to fix your `Get-ADUser` call,
- and you should also add code that detects the case of that call unexpectedly returning no objects.

The following snippet demonstrates the latter, and it also streamlines your command by passing the output from `Get-ADUser` directly to `Set-ADUser`:

```
# Get the users of interest and pass them to the Set-ADUser call to update
# the City property.
# Note the use of -OutputVariable users, which saves the output from 
# Get-ADUser in variable $users
Get-ADUser -OutputVariable users -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=...' | Set-ADUser -City 'Alice'

# Report terminating error if no users were found.
# Note: -not $users returns $true if $users is an empty collection
#       (or a similarly "falsy" value such as $null, 0, or '').
if (-not $users) { Throw "Get-ADUser unexpectedly returned nothing." }
```